# MySql Finding Reading and Fuel Consumption Average of Vehicle

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in a vehicle management database.

1. table_vehicle_info consists of Vehicle Information like its registration no etc
2. tbl_readings store Daily readings of the Vehicle
3. tbl_vehicle_expenses stores Fuel Expenses.

tbl_readings and tbl_vehicle_expenses are joined to table_vehicle_info through vehicle_id column.

I need to take the average fuel consumption per KM for each Vehicle for a given Month/Year. The Database Structure is at

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26bcb5

To calculate the Fuel for any given Month

```
SELECT fuel_cost*fuel_price AS 'TPRICE', V.reg_no FROM tbl_vehicle_expense POL 
INNER JOIN table_vehicle_info V ON V.id=POL.`vehicle_id`
WHERE MONTH(e_date)=10 
GROUP BY vehicle_id
```

To Find Readings for any given Month i use the following query.

```
SELECT MAX(km_driven)-MIN(km_driven) AS 'KM', V.`reg_no` FROM tbl_readings R
INNER JOIN table_vehicle_info V ON V.`id`=R.`vehicle_id`

 WHERE MONTH(dt_of_reading)=10 GROUP BY vehicle_id
```

How do i find out the Litre per Km use and how do i find out the total Average

Comment: What is this obsession with prefixing tables with tbl? Do they teach that somewhere?

Comment: object grouping. table starts with tbl prefix views with view etc

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: Desired Result should be like Vehicle_reg_no | km_driven | Fuel_consumed | Mileage